# Code minification of angular app using grunt concat and uglify

Tags: angularjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm using grunt concat and uglify to minify angular app however the minified script is giving the following error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%…2F%2F192.168.1.244%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fmyapp.min.js%3A5%3A10649)(…)

This is how I have implemented DI in the angular application.

```js
(function() {
    myapp
    
    .controller('MyController',MyController);

    MyController.$inject = ['$scope','$rootScope'];
 
    function MyController($scope,$rootScope) {
      
    }
})();
```

This is how my gruntfile looks.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  concat: {
   dist: {
    src: ['node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js','node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js','node_modules/angular/angular.min.js'],
    dest: 'dist/js/myapp.js',
   }
  },
   uglify: {
   options: {
    report: 'min',
    mangle: false
   },
   my_target: {
    files: {
     'dist/js/myapp.min.js':['dist/js/myapp.js']
    }
   }
  }
 });
 
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
};
```

I'm following the proper DI method for angular and why's the error still occuring?

Comment: That's weird, are you sure the error is caused by this controller in particular?